# How do I stop flinging people to their death?

Tags: gravity-rush

When I gravity-shift from a street, I frequently pick up a straggler or two that is then launched either into the abyss or so high that a return trip would be fatal.

The citizens don't seem to begrudge me the occasional accidental manslaughter, but will they eventually clue into why people keep disappearing/falling from the sky around Kat?

Is there a way to stop taking people with me besides jumping off the city's edge before shifting?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread that as fingering.

Comment: Plus one just for the title!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to avoid dragging innocent people into their doom. If you still feel bad about it, just make sure nobody is in your vicinity, as you use your powers.

Interestingly, no matter how high they fell from, they don't die; it appears they will only die if you make them fall repeatedly to their "death", or if you beat them up often enough.

Regardless of whether you "bother" them, "accidentally" kill them, or not, it is of no consequence in the game. Your reputation won't suffer either.

Comment: What a cold-hearted world. :'(